# what is the type of data expected in RSA_verify, can't verify a signature generated from Java

Tags: java, c++, openssl, digital-signature

I create a signature on Java using :

```
String message = "my message";
byte[] data = message.getBytes();
byte[] result;
Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA512withRSA");
sig.initSign(this.privateKey);
sig.update(data);
result = sig.sign();
```

Then I save result as a Hex String into a text file, and using openssl I try to verify:

```
string signature//read hex string in the text file 
string message = "my message";
RSA *rsaPkey = NULL;

FILE *pemFile;
fopen_s(&pemFile, publicKeyFile, "r");
rsaPkey = PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY(pemFile, &rsaPkey, NULL, NULL);
fclose(pemFile);

if(rsaPkey == NULL)
{
    RSA_free(rsaPkey);
    return 0;
}

int type                = NID_sha512;
const char *m           = message.c_str();
unsigned int m_len      = message.length();
int size                = RSA_size(rsaPkey);
unsigned char *sigret   = (unsigned char*) signature.c_str();
unsigned int siglen     = signature.length();

unsigned char digest[SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];

SHA512_CTX ctx;
SHA512_Init(&ctx);
SHA512_Update(&ctx, m, m_len);
SHA512_Final(digest, &ctx);

int r = RSA_verify(type, digest, SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH, sigret, siglen, rsaPkey);
```

`r` is always 0, which means the verification has failed. I think it's because it's expecting the message or the signature in a specific format than the hex I got from Java but i don't know what exaclty.

**UPDATE**

After using the digest as suggested by Pras, I get this message error when I use ERR_get_error : 
`error:04091068:rsa routines:INT_RSA_VERIFY:bad signature`

Answer (score 1):

From RSA_verify() man page:

> RSA_verify() verifies that the signature sigbuf of size siglen matches
>   a given message digest m of size m_len. type denotes the message
>   digest algorithm that was used to generate the signature. rsa is the
>   signer's public key.

So the second and third arguments are supposed to be message digest and digest length not actual message and message length that was signed

Comment: you're right, I've just tried with the digest but still getting 0. I updated the question maybe i'm still missing something

Answer (score 0):

It could be that `byte[] data = message.getBytes();` may not give the same sequence of bytes as `message.c_str()`. I suggest you check it with a debugger.

Comment: they're the same

Comment: You were lucky. You should have used the long form, specifying the character set.